# Solving second order ODE with a series solution.

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi guys I would really like some feedback on my work. I am making assumptions on the form of the solution and where I expand the power series, I am not sure if those are correct.

Problem:

$$t(1-t)y''-3ty'-y=0$$

Hint: you should be able to express the solution in
closed form. Using this closed form solution, find a second solution.

My work.

Because it was not specified where to center the power series I decided to center it at $t=0$. I do not know if that is a good a bad idea because we have a regular singularity at $t=0$.

Then assume $y= \sum _0 ^\infty a_n t^{(n+r)}$ form there we can obtain $y'=\sum  _0 ^\infty w a_n t^{w-1}$ and $y''= \sum _0 ^ \infty w(w-1)a_n t^{w-2}$ where I used $w= n+r$ for ease.

Now taking the power series and pluging in the equation we obtain

$$(t-t^2)\sum _0 ^ \infty w(w-1)a_n t^{w-2}-3t\sum  _0 ^\infty w a_n t^{w-1}-\sum _0 ^\infty a_n t^{(n+r)}=0$$

We distrubite and simplify

$$\sum_0 w(w-1)a_nt^{w-1}- \sum_0 w(w-1) a_n t^w-3\sum_0 wa_n x^w - \sum_0 an x^w=0$$

Now I multiply the equation by t and shift the three sums to the right by 1.

$$\sum_0 w(w-1) t^w - \sum_1 a_{n-1} (w-1)(w-2)t^w-3\sum_1 a_{n-1}(w-1)t^w-\sum_1 a_{n-1} t^w=0$$.

Now focusing on the first sum we see that the $a_0$ term (indicial equation) is $a_0(r)(r-1)t^r=0$ thus $r=0, r=1$ thus the solution should be of the form $y=y_1+y_2$ where $y_i=t^{r_i}$( $\sum a's$).
When now let us focus on $a_n$ in general we see that
$$a_n(w)(w-1)=(w-1)(w-2)+3(w-1)+1 a_{n-1}$$
Say we look at $r=1$ and simplify we get

$$a_n= \frac{n+1}{n}a_n{n-1}$$

from there I get the series 
$$(1+t+2t^2+3t^3+\dots)$$

Thus $y_1=t^1(1+t+2t^2+3t^3+\dots)$, from here I do not see how this relates to the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+t+t^2+t^3+\cdots =\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n= \frac{1}{1-t}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n=1+2t+3t^2+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)t^n=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1-t}=-\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$$
Now, you say that $y_1=t+t^2+2t^3+3t^4+\cdots$ so that
$$y_1=t+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)t^{n+2}=t+t^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)t^n$$
$$=t+t^2(-\frac{1}{(1-t)^2})=t-\frac{t^2}{(1-t)^2}$$
This is the closed form solution, if all your other work is correct. I believe the hint is for you to use [reduction of order](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx) to find the other solution.

Do you have boundary conditions for this ODE? If not, the problem is a little ill-defined.

Comment: No boundary Conditions were specified.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{1-t}=-\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}=\sum_n nt^{n-1}=\frac{1}{t}(1+t+2t^2+3t^3+\cdots) \\
\end{align}

Therefore,

\begin{align}
(1+t+2t^2+3t^3+\cdots)=-\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}
\end{align}